# ScorePayload doesn't get called on CustomSimilarity

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

I followed this blogpost but in lucene.net:

https://lucidworks.com/post/getting-started-with-payloads/

This is how my custom Similarity Looks like:

```
public class PayloadSimilarity : DefaultSimilarity
{
    public override float ScorePayload(int doc, int start, int end, BytesRef payload) 
    {
        var score = PayloadHelper.DecodeSingle(payload.Bytes, start);

        return score;
    }
}
```

Then as the blog post mentions I set the similarity for the Searcher and as well as for the indexer. 
In luke I can see that the Payload is there. And if I search for the payloads it doesn't give me back anything so I think the payload is there but the Searcher doesn't takes into the account.

I'm using Query Parser with the combination of Searcher and the custom similariity.

The explain shows that my custom similarity was used but it doesn't show that ScorePayload was used, and of course it doesn't break in the ScorePayload function if I put a breakpoint there.

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S: And this is how I build the Analyzer:

```
    public static Analyzer WithTermBasedBoosting(char delimiter) => CustomAnalyzer
        .WithTokenizer("WhitespaceTokenizer")
        .AddTokenFilter("DelimitedPayloadTokenFilter")
        .With(delimiter,new SingleEncoder())
        .Build();
```

For the sake of simplicity I created another Analyzer with the fewest things:

```
    public static Analyzer MyDelimited(char delimiter) => Analyzer.NewAnonymous(createComponents: (fieldName, reader) =>
    {
        Tokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer(CustomAnalyzer.Version, reader);

        TokenStream filter = new DelimitedPayloadTokenFilter(source, delimiter, new SingleEncoder());

        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the answer was simple, you can't use a normal QueryParser as it doesn't takes into account the payload. I found out a QueryTerm type namely PayloadTermQuery and now my Query looks like this:

```
public List<ResultModel> Query(string indexName,string searchTerm, int top = 100, float score = 2f)
        {
            var searcher = GetSearcher(indexName);

            //Query query = new QueryParser(Version, IndexFields.Text, _queryAnalyzer).Parse(searchTerm);

            Query query = new PayloadTermQuery(new Term(IndexFields.Text, "GMBH"), new AveragePayloadFunction());

            var rowsToReturn = top == 0 ? int.MaxValue : top;

            var hits = searcher.Search(query, rowsToReturn).ScoreDocs;

            return hits.Where(x => x.Score >= score)
                .Select(hit => hit.ToResultModel(searcher, query))
                .ToList();
        }
```

However would be great to use QueryParser with the combination of the CustomSimilarity.